# one to one relationship modelling

Tags: sql, oracle-sql-data-modeler

How can we create one to one relationship in Oracle sql data modeler

Answer (score 1):

1. Double-click on the line connecting the `table` to itself.
2. Go to the Comments tab.
3. Set the `cardinality property` to **1..1**.

By default, if you don't set the `cardinality` property, the `relationship` is `many-to-one`.

[image]

Sources: [Oracle Modelling guide](http://onewebsql.com/docs/1_0_x/official/oracle-modeling-guide/oracle-modeling-guide.html#toc17) , [Jeff Fish blog](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/data-modeling/)

Answer (score 1):

Edit the table that has the FK and add a unique constraint on the FK column. Once you do that the diagram will update into a "one to" relation.

Answer (score 0):

Set the foreign key as primary key, then the relation symbol changes automatically.

[image]